# How to remove @&hellip;@ from Joomla

Tags: html, joomla3.0

My Joomla website automatically shows &helllip; in the article. How to remove? [Error Screenshot Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRQlr.jpg) Actually the article name is "Current Advances In non-surgical Cosmetic & Therapies". But in the front end of Joomla it has automatically translated to Current "Advances In non-surgical Cosmeti…". I have checked the back end, everything is fine there.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Are you asking why an ellipsis ( . . . ) shows up in your text, or are you asking why the HTML symbol for ellipsis (`&hellip;`) shows up. We need a bit more info. Perhaps post some of your code

Comment: try using php function html_entity_decode() around the text and test

Comment: can you check what text is exactly stored in database using phpmyadmin